# Employee count each year-more slicing

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is the code used for computing the count of employees in each year. how can i use this code for finding India and US region employee count in each year without using any buttons?

```
EmpCount_Year  = 
CALCULATE (
         COUNT('TABLE1'[Employee ID]) ,
         FILTER ('TABLE1',
         FILTER ( VALUES('Date'[Year]),'TABLE1'[Joining Date]<=MAX('Date'[Date])
                &&  (
        'TABLE1'[Last Working Date] >= MAX('Date'[Date]) ||  
         ISBLANK('TABLE1'[Last Working Date])
                    )
                    )
                    )
                    )
```

Comment: Can you show a shot of your table structure?